# Understanding what Self.Generator.Element is in Swift map definition

Tags: swift, functional-programming, closures

Swift noob here.

Many functions have the Self.Generator.Element in the parameters of the closure definition. What the heck is it? I tried to go to the definition and it took me no where.

```
public func map<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a chain of the resolved types of generic protocols. Self is the adopter of this generic protocol, which has an associated type called Generator which adopts GeneratorType, which is itself a generic protocol, which has an associated type called Element. So Self.Generator.Element is whatever *that* type resolves to.

This chain lies at the basis of the relationship between a sequence (or collection) and its elements. For example, if Self is CollectionType, then Self.Generator.Element is the type of the collection's elements.

Thus, for instance, an Array of String, type `Array<String>` or `[String]`, is a Collection whose Self.Generator.Element is String. And so the `map` method's `transform` function (in your example) would take a String as its parameter.

(Note that `map` says nothing about what type is output by the `transform` function; it is a pure generic placeholder, T. The compiler expects to be able to resolve T when it sees the actual function at compile time.)

Comment: That makes sense. "Thus, for instance, an Array of String, type Array<String> or [String], is a Collection whose Self.Generator.Element is String." I kind of knew but reading someone else say made it sit right. Thanks.

Comment: More in my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_associated_type_chains

Comment: Thank you. Your online book seems a lot easier to digest than official documentation.